# How to support multiple private npm packages living in one git repo?

Tags: git, node.js, github, npm

`npm` is very good at supporting packages publishes to the global/central `npm` repo, which doesn't work well for private, application code.  `npm` also supports adding a git repo as a dependency, which lets you have a private dependency.

The problem is, as I understand to be best practice, my `npm` packages tend to be very tight and small, whereas my git repos tend to be larger, and will include several `npm` packages.  I do not know any way to attain this granularity while pointing to a github URL.  How to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I accepted the answer that says "don't do this, stay on the rails." I agree with this recommendation, but YMMV.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. What's wrong with having multiple git repositories?

Comment: @TheHippo github charges per repo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest that one repo with multiple packages is a bad idea to start with for several reasons. You should be viewing a package as its own entity: independently built, tested, and deployed. All that to say, each package should live in its own repo.

That being said, I definitely understand the benefit of being able to do an `npm install <package-group>` of one "commons" package and have it grab all the packages you need in one shot. I would suggest looking at the [grunt-contrib model](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib) for accomplishing this. In short, they have a bunch of grunt-contrib- packages (ex. grunt-contrib-coffee) each living in their own repositories. They then create a separate repository that defines the parent "grunt-contrib" package. All this parent package does is specify dependencies on all of the sub-packages. This allows you to do an `npm install grunt-contrib-coffee` (for example) and get just the grunt-contrib-coffee package; or you can do `npm install grunt-contrib` and get their entire suite all in one shot.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Independently building, testing and deploying is unrelated to independently checking in. Thanks for the grunt rec, will look into at some point.

Comment: @Jacob - You are saying that package is "own entity", "independently build, tested, and deployed" which is all fine, but your conclusion is "each package should live in its own repo" which does not comply with logic, this argument is out of space. One repository (or so called mono-repos) has many advantages like: you can do integration tests between components easier, you can easier develop them as a whole. For me this is ideal for multiple connected packages which share interfaces. I think it's bad to add ideology because of tool limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set up your own local npm repository.

- [Instructions for *nix/OSX](https://web.archive.org/web/20130806213230/http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository)
- [Instructions for Windows](http://ponderingdeveloper.com/2013/03/18/setting-up-a-local-npm-registry-on-windows/)